# Angular2 Typescript .NET Core VS2015. Cannot find name 'Promise', 'Set', 'Map'

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I'm following the Angular2 quickstart guide (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) to build a web application using Typescript and .NET Core. Dependencies and typings are resolved and generated correctly, but when i try to build, i get the errors:

TS2304 Build:Cannot find name 'Set'

TS2304 Build:Cannot find name 'Promise'

TS2304 Build:Cannot find name 'Map'

As i read in many other questions, i could resolve by targeting the Typescript compiler to ES6 ("target": "es6" in tsconfig.json), but this is not an option as many browsers still doesn't support ES6. So  i tried to add the typings for "es6-promise" and "es6-collections" in my typings.json file:

```
{
   "globalDependencies":  {
     "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160725163759",
     "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
     "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160909174046",
     "es6-promise": "registry:dt/es6-promise", 
     "es6-collections": "registry:dt/es6-collections"
  }
}
```

But it still doesn't compile. What can i try to do to compile in ES5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add the references to the ES6 typings in my **main.ts** file:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/globals/es6-promise/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../typings/globals/es6-collections/index.d.ts" />
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

I don't know if there's a better solution, but in this way i can build succesfully in ES5.

Comment: In the `typings` folder, there should also be a `index.d.ts` file which automatically includes all the type definitions you have installed. So you do not need to include the individual type definitions but just that single file.

Comment: @poke yes, there's the index.d.ts in the typings folder, with all the references (even the es6 typings), but it doesn't work, i don't know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and installing the es6-shim

```
typings install dt~es6-shim --save --global
```

and referencing the same

```
///<reference path="typings/globals/es6-shim/index.d.ts"/>
```

has fix it.